# Why is the network activity LED keeps on blinking nonstop really fast?

Tags: networking, ethernet, desktop, led

I never noticed my desktop's Ethernet network activity light or LED is blinking all the time NONSTOP until couple of months ago. I think it was always that way whole time, but my question is why. I thought it was the other way around. It only blinks when there is a transfer of data and other times it stayed off. I have firewall and antivirus software running. So, I don't think my computer is hacked. What would be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

It does only blink when there's data being transferred, but there's always data being transferred, even when you're not doing anything with the network yourself. There are all kinds of things to keep the network infrastructure working like ARP requests, broadcast messages, service announcements, and so on. They're not very much data, but they're very frequent.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost always data being transferred although you are not directly causing the data usage. There could be many possible reasons of this frequent data usage. To find out what programs are using this data being transferred, you can open task manager and sort by network usage.